# ACF acf_form on admin page works, but when it is loaded in via ajax it breaks

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using acf_form() to embed a form in a metabox on the admin page using this code (simplified):

```
$submitted_user_id = 'user_3';

$form_settings = array(

    'fields' => ['field_625008b509dca'],

    'form_attributes' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'action' => admin_url("admin-post.php"),
    ),

    'post_id' => $submitted_user_id,

);

acf_form( $form_settings );
```

..and calling the requisite acf_form_head() in admin_init as such:

```
function append_acf_form_head() {

   acf_form_head();

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'append_acf_form_head', 1 );
```

This works fine, and updates the values on submit. However I want to pull this form in via ajax, in order to pass the user_id from a select filter above.

The ajax is also working perfectly, and pulling in the form with the passed user_id, however on submission the form does not save the data, and redirects to 'wp-admin/admin-post.php'.

This is the php code for the ajax functionality in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_action', 'test_action' );
function test_action() {

    // Same acf_form() function as above

    wp_die()

}
```

And finally the JS:

```
$('button#support-ticket-user-filter').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        'action': 'test_action',
        'user_id': $('select#get_user_id').val()
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $('#listings-result').append( response );

    });

});
```

Any ideas why it would work perfectly in the first case, but not in the second? Perhaps it's related to the ajaxurl?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you share what error your getting

Comment: So it's not actually throwing an error and there's nothing in debug.log. What is happening is that it shows the 'Do you want to leave the page' popup and then if yes, redirects to wp-admin/admin-post.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the solution; I've found a slightly hacky approach which does the trick for now. The ACF Support team mentioned this wasn't out the box functionality but has now been included as a feature request. For those trying to achieve this the trick is to permanently embed a 'dummy form' which loads the necessary stuff to make it all work - then kind of hook this into the form pulled in via ajax:

So, in the meta box a permanent dummy form is embedded:

```
// This dummy form is required to load all the acf stuff for the ajax version 

$dummy_form_settings = array(

     // Do not declare any fields

    'post_id' => $submitted_user_id, // Make sure the ID corresponds ( for users in my case )

    'form' => true,

);

acf_form( $dummy_form_settings );
```

All we want from this dummy form is the 'update' button - which is the one that actually works, as opposed to the one in the form pulled in via ajax. So that function will remove the submit button like this:

```
$form_settings = array(

    'fields' => ['field_625008b509dca'],

    'form_attributes' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
    ),

    'html_before_fields' => sprintf(
        '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="' . $submitted_user_id . '">',
    ),

    'post_id' => $submitted_user_id,

    'form' => true,

    'html_submit_button' => '', // The important bit

);

acf_form( $form_settings );

wp_die();
```

Now your essentially left with a single form that submits properly.